# Django, HTML, JS: <img src="#"> work in HTML but in JS file not

Tags: javascript, html, django, src

If I call `<img src="{% static "images/loader.gif" %}" alt="loader.gif"/>`in *home.html*, the gif is displayed (so this should mean that it points correctly to the required folder) **but** if i try to call it in a js file, the broken icon  appears ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6j3qz7)).
Is there a different way to call the images in a JS file (compared to an Html file)?

my situation:

**home.html**

```
    ...
    <script src="{% static 'js/conta.js' %}"> </script>

    <a href="{% url 'conta' %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" id="btnGo">GO</a><div id="loading"></div>
    ...
```

**conta.js**

```
    $('#btnGO').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  

        $(this)
            .removeClass('btn-primary')
            .addClass('btn-danger disabled') 
            .text('WAIT');

        $('#loading').html('<img src="static/images/loader.gif" alt="loader.gif"/> loading...');

                        $.get("/conta/", function() {       
                           alert("FINISH");                    



        $('#btnGo')
            .removeClass('btn-danger disabled')
            .addClass('btn-primary') 
            .text('GO');

        $('#loading').html(''); 


        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.js` file is not processed by tempate system so template tags are not work here.  Use the hard-coded path to your images:

```
$('#loading').html(
         '<img src="/static/images/loader.gif" alt="loader.gif"/> loading...');
```

Comment: I had already tried but it does not work...maybe it is not clear for me the term 'relative path' at this point ( I tried with `<img src="static/images/loader.gif" alt="loader.gif"/>`). Static is in the parent directory of my project. I updated the code (thanks for the explanation about `{% static  ..%}`)

Comment: My initial recipe was wrong.  Relative paths are used with CSS styling.  So simplest way for you is to use absolute hard-coded path.  Add the `/` slash before the `static` (look at updated answer).

Comment: Thanks! only for a "/"!!